# Structured constants in QML

Tags: qt, qml, constants

Based on other posts (across sites), I have created a Constants.qml file which contains:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.6

QtObject {
    readonly property alias MyConst: myConst_

    QtObject
    {
        id: myConst_
        readonly property int Test: 1
        readonly property int Apple: 2
        readonly property int Dog: 4
    }
}
```

And elsewhere I am trying to reference these values like this:

```
var a = Constants.MyConst.Test
```

Which generates error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Test' of undefined
```

Can someone explain how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with lower case:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.6

QtObject {
    readonly property alias myConst: myConst_

    QtObject
    {
        id: myConst_
        readonly property int test: 1
        readonly property int apple: 2
        readonly property int dog: 4
    }
}
```

Comment: Really? I do exactly this in my code. The only other thing that looks odd is that you capitalize the first letter of everything. Sometimes that matters. Try starting property names with lowercase. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Same problem with lower case.  Could it be the way I'm referencing the keys?  (Per question)

Comment: With lowercase key names autocomplete in the Qt Creator editor now completes the names.  But at run time the error is the same

Comment: Are you adding `import "./"` where you try to access the singleton?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is handy to put all constants to a separate JS file, for example:

```
// cosntants.js
.pragma library
var TEST = 1
var Apple = "x"
var dOg = 3.14
```

And use it in QML like:

```
// main.qml
import "cosntants.js" as JS
...
var a = JS.TEST + JS.Apple
```

Of course you can make them structured, just use plain JS objects for this. You can check out my [project](https://github.com/QtRoS/ameditation/tree/master/qml) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and in my case the solution was to add a file named qmldir in the same folder as the Constants.qml file, with contents:

```
singleton Constants Constants.qml
```